can i search "Message ID" on CloudWatchLogs?
I have a C# application in which I am using the AWS SDK to use AWS SNS to send SMS. When I send SMS, AWS SNS is configured to log the details of the sending to AWS CloudWatchLogs, for example, if the SMS was sent successfully or if it had an error.
When I send the SMS I get the MessageID of the sending and store it in my database, but when I want to search in AWS CloudWatchLogs I cannot search by that data because this is an attribute of the log created in AWS CloudWatchLogs but it is not the name of the log in AWS CloudWatchLogs.
I can get all the records from AWS CloudWatchLogs and by browsing through them I can access the MessageID, but I think it is too inefficient beacause I would have to go through all the records until I find the one I need.
Is there a way to search by the MessageID?
This is how I'm searching for all the records
            var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsKeyId, awsKeySecret);

            AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient client = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(awsCredentials,Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
           

            
            var describeLogStreamsRequest = new DescribeLogStreamsRequest()
            {
                LogGroupName = "sns/us-east-1/xxxxxxxxx/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber" 
            };

            var describeLogStreamsResult = await client.DescribeLogStreamsAsync(describeLogStreamsRequest);

            foreach (var stream in describeLogStreamsResult.LogStreams)
            {
                var eventsRequest = new GetLogEventsRequest()
                {
                    LogStreamName = stream.LogStreamName,
                    LogGroupName = describeLogStreamsRequest.LogGroupName,
                    StartFromHead = true
                };
                var result =await client.GetLogEventsAsync(eventsRequest);
                foreach (var events in result.Events)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(events.Timestamp + "  - " + events.Message);
                }
            }


do you really want to search the logs using c#? You could also set up SNS as event destination and be notified about the status directly. Event-driven instead of searching in the logs. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sms-voice/latest/userguide/configuration-sets-sns.html .
Otherwise, you can also use Log Insights to query the logs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudWatchLogs/MCloudWatchLogsStartQueryStartQueryRequest.html .
